# help with simple darboux integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

consider $f\left(x\right)\:=\:\frac{1}{x}$ in $\left[1,2\right]$.

how to find a $\delta >0$ such that for every partition $P$ of $\left[1,2\right]$ that implement $\Delta P\:<\delta $ wiil be:
$\left|U\left(f,P\right)-L\left(f,P\right)\right|\:<\:0.001$

i don't know how to even start. i think i need to begin with "let's take some P that held the $\left|U\left(f,P\right)-L\left(f,P\right)\right|\:<\:0.001$ and then i struggle..

tnx!

Comment: If, one every interval of length $\leqslant \delta$, the values of $f$ differ by at most $\omega(\delta)$, then the difference between the upper and lower sum is at most $\omega(\delta)\cdot (b-a)$ if $[a,b]$ is the interval you're integrating over.